# Load very big CSV-Files into s SQL-Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, csv

Is there a performant way to load very big CSV-files (which have size of several gigabytes) into an SQL-Server 2008 database with .NET?

Answer (score 7):

I would combine [this CSV reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) with [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx); i.e.

```
using (var file = new StreamReader(path))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(file, true)) // true = has header row
using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) {
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
    bcp.WriteToServer(csv);
}
```

This uses the bulk-copy API to do the inserts, while using a fully-managed (and fast) `IDataReader` implementation (crucially, which **streams** the data, rather than loading it all at once).

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlBulkCopy
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx